# exif support is enabled but read_exif_data returns NULL every time

Tags: php, exif

This is driving me up the wall.   In phpinfo() the line '--enable-exif' is present in the 'configure command' section, and the exif section of phpinfo is as follows...

```
EXIF Support            enabled
EXIF Version            1.4 $Id: exif.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF
```

and I am even able to confirm the function exists...

```
        if (function_exists(read_exif_data)){
```

but no matter what file I try it on,  it returns NULL...

```
    if (function_exists(read_exif_data)){
        $exif = read_exif_data("this_file_definitely_has_exif_data.jpg");   
        var_dump($exif);
    }
```

outputs 'NULL'

I know it's finding the file to begin with because if I 'break' the file string it will generate an error.  It does not generate any errors with valid file string,  just NULL.

I'm on a shared host so I can't recompile apache or anything like that.

edit:  I have discovered my host supports Imagick so I can use that instead to get the info I need,  but it'd still be interesting to know why this is failing.

Comment: read_exif_data is an alias for exif_read_data http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php, try reading the notes on that page re: --enable-mbstring

Comment: Cups,  --enable-mbstring is listed without '=shared' in the configure command section.  I think that means it's correctly configured according to those notes.

Comment: can you confirm that the file is exists? maybe using if(file_exists())?

Comment: I proved the file exists by breaking the filename string and getting an error as a result of doing so.  But I added file_exists to the code and it does exist.